# Input type="file" changes file name

Tags: html, file-upload

while i am try to upload (`.url`) file at that time it changes file name as well as file path. it will takes path from Internet Temporary File address.

i want to get original file name and original file path.

please Help me.

Comment: Which programming language did you used ?

Comment: Maybe url files are handled like Links. That mean that the content is trannsmitted and not the link itself. That would explain your behavior.

Comment: java, but it's a common html problem you just create simple html file with file upload field and then try to upload .url file it will show you temp file address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the original file name or path from a file input. They are obscured to protect the user's privacy and security (the structure of their file system is not the business of websites they interact with).

The purpose of a file input is to allow the *content of a file* to be submitted, not meta data about the file.

Comment: only (.url) file having this type of problem other wise it works fine i don't know how to solve this problem i want original file name.